# how to build a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'd like to learn how to build a rake task for my rails 3 app that does two things.

1. Pushes assets to the CDN
2. Deploys to heroku

**Commands for the above steps:**

```
 rake cache:s3
 heroku jammit:deploy --app #{app}
```

Here's what I have /lib/tasks/deployer.rake

```
task :deployit do
  puts '=== Storing assets on s3 ==='
  run "rake cache:s3"
  puts '=== Deploying to Heroku ==='
  run "heroku jammit:deploy --app #{app}"
end

def run(cmd)
  shell cmd
  if $?.exitstatus == 0
    display "[OK]"
  else
    display "[FAIL]"
  end
end
```

But that errors with 'undefined method `shell' for main:Object'

Suggestions on how to make this work? Should this be a task or something else?

Thanks

Comment: http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first task is another rake task, which will run if it is a dependency of the `:deployit` task. Your current code would loads rake twice.

If you use system like Arun suggested you would get:

```
task :deployit => 'cache:s3' do
  puts '=== Deploying to Heroku ==='
  system "heroku jammit:deploy --app #{app}"
end
```

Comment: Heroku is a gem so it might even be possible to just call the jammit:deploy by requiring it in this task. I took a quick look at the gem but failed to find which methods should be called.

Answer (score 2):

Use system command instead. For more info: http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

Comment: mind updating with new code? Also the def run... does that work ina task?